# How can I get the spacing right please?

Tags: html

I'm not the greatest with HTML, but I'm also not the worse, as in I know how to locate and change things with instructions, but that's about it.

Is anyone able to help me please?

I am trying to get these two menu's separated/spaced out, ideally the main menu links to the left, and the social media links to the right, I have included two images below that hopefully explains what I'm looking to achieve.

[This is how it looks on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Ssn.png)

[This is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NzUi.png)

Hopefully I have put the right bit of code below, as I initially said I'm not great with HTML at all.

```
# 7. Navigation
-----------------------------------------------*/
#social-menu .social-links a {
color: $(topmenu.text.color);
}
#social-menu .social-links a:hover {
color: $(topmenu.text.hover.color);
}
.menu-wrap {
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 7;
word-break: break-word !important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
text-align: center;
}
#menu-secondary {
max-width: 1180px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-top: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#nav-secondary {
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#nav-primary {
position: static;
height: 50px;
background: $(topmenu.bg.color);
}

.wrapper-nav-primary {
max-width: 92%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background: $(topmenu.bg.color);
padding: 0 4%;
z-index: 999;
}

#menu-primary {
width: 70%;
float: left;
visibility: hidden;
}

#social-menu {
float: right;
margin-top: 18px;
}
.menu-wrap .widget {
display: inline-block;
}

.menu-wrap li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.menu-wrap li,
.menu-wrap ul {
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 50px;
}

.menu-wrap li a {
margin: 0 30px;
font-weight: 400 !important;
}

#nav-primary li a {
color: $(topmenu.text.color);
}

#nav-primary li a:hover {
color: $(topmenu.text.hover.color);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably be good to post the HTML as well :)

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for replying. Oh dear, have I messed up already haha? I thought the 'code' I had put with my post is the HTML, have I got that wrong?

Comment: haha no it's fine, you've only given us one bit, to make it easier for people to help we would need the HTML and the CSS - to get the HTML part you could load the page in your browser, right click on a empty bit of the page and 'view source' - then look for something like '<div class="header">' then you will need to find the closing </div> - don't post the entire page though, someone will moan at you ;)

Comment: Thank's so much Andy, your help is much appreciated. I think I have located the correct piece, however when I am trying to copy and paste as a new comment on here, it's saying I am 3000 characters over the maximum allowance. I have tripple checked I'm not doing the whole page too. I think it may be because it's a blogger website maybe?

Comment: ok, maybe just grab the navigation part maybe then? which could be the 'menu-wrap' bit you have in the CSS above

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can add the following to the #social-menu. If you can supply the HTML implementation, and not only the CSS it will be easier to determine.

```
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I am trying to find the way to post the HTML, it's saying I'm 3000 characters over the limit. I won't give up, hopefully I'll be able to get that info soon, I am going to see if I can break it down as lots of the HTML is showing as links! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both again for your help, I feel very silly as the solution was simply going to the Blogger layout section and simply moving a box!

I spent the whole of yesterday trying to sort this, following various tutorials and guides changing the HTML and adding CSS haha.

[The red HTML/JavaScript box in the primary menu section should be in the social media section below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFBVj.png)